# Using an index for both uniqueness and fast lookup?

Tags: postgresql, index

Right now I have a postgresql 8.4 database set up for players in a multiplayer game. I want the username column to be unique. I also want to be able to lookup a player by username quickly. Here's the output of `\d players`:

```
                            Table "public.players"
   Column   |  Type   |                      Modifiers                       
------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------
 id         | bigint  | not null default nextval('players_id_seq'::regclass)
 username   | text    | not null
 trophies   | integer | 
Indexes:
    "pk_id" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "players_username_key" UNIQUE, btree (username)
    "players_trophies_index" btree (trophies DESC NULLS LAST)
    "players_username_index" btree (username)
```

I'm not a DBA, so bear with me. This seems like an inefficient use of disk space by having two indices on the username column: one for uniqueness and one for fast lookup. Is it possible to combine them into one index, maintaining uniqueness and fast lookup? If so, are there any drawbacks to such an approach?

Comment: Consider upgrading PostgreSQL as it is rather old now...

Comment: Yeah, will have to when I start using replication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need a single index, the unique one. Queries to lookup by `username` will use the unique index. There's no advantage to having a second index on the same column marked as non-unique.

You can verify that this by performing an `EXPLAIN` on the query. Connect to you database and compare the results of the following before and after you drop the index and confirm that they are the same:

```
EXPLAIN VERBOSE
SELECT *
FROM public.players
WHERE username = 'foobar'
```

In both cases it should show something like:

```
Index scan using using players_username_key on public.players (cost=...[truncated])
  Output: id, username, trophies ...
```

Comment: Thanks. In both cases, the cost was `cost=0.00..2.41 rows=1 width=540`.

Comment: I expected the size of the database returned by `SELECT pg_database_size()` to decrease after dropping the unneeded index. Why did the database size stay the same? I should mention that there are only 35 rows currently.

Comment: See here for a list of possibilities as to why the space isn't immediately reclaimed: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16901/dropping-indexes-doesnt-seem-to-release-space-to-the-os-can-it

Answer (score 1):

With index duplication you not only waste disk space, but also increase the overhead for changes to the table.  Each additional index increases the time to add and delete rows, and may increase the time for updates.

This is the worst type of key duplication, and as noted only the Unique index is necessary.  The entries in the other index will be unique, but may not be as efficiently stored, as the index needs to handle non-unique entries.

I also run across indexes which are a subset of another index.  These are usually not required, although in some cases may be justifiable.  Rarely have my tests shown significant query speed improvement from the extra index.

Comment: Thanks. It's helpful to recognize this as a duplicate index situation.

Comment: @NatWeiss The first two paragraphs apply in your case, only the third extends the situation, but as you have a duplicate index, you may run into the situation noted in the third.